# How to get subset of two arrays in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

What I am trying to do is if I have Array
*a = {1,2,3,4};
b = {1,2};*

Then I want subset array as *c = {3,4};*

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Please clarify your terminology.  In your example `c` is indeed a subset of `a`, but you have not indicated why that's the particular subset you want.  Did you perhaps been the relative complement of `b` in `a`, i.e. `b \ a`?  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_%28mathematics%29#Complements

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not aware of any built-in way to do this, you basically have to loop through `c` and check whether each element is in `a` and, if so, remove it. The [`Array#indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) method can help you with checking, but not all implementations have it (though most do). Removal can be via [`Array#splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice).

So:

```
var a, c, index;
a = [1, 2];
c = [1, 2, 3, 4];
for (index = c.length - 1; index >= 0; --index) {
    if (a.indexOf(c[index]) >= 0) {
        c.splice(index, 1);
    }
}
```

...and then either supply your own implementation of `Array#indexOf` if your environment doesn't support it, or use a library like [Prototype](http://prototypejs.org) that supplies it for you (jQuery gives it to you as well, but through its own [`jQuery.inArray`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/) function). If doing it yourself:

```
if (!Array.prototype.indexOf) {
  (function() {
    Array.prototype.indexOf = Array_indexOf;
    function Array_indexOf(elm) {
      var index;
      for (index = 0; index < this.length; ++index) {
        if (this[index] === elm) {
          return index;
        }
      }
      return -1;
    }
  })();
}
```

Note that adding to the `Array` prototype as above can be dangerous when done with <s>poorly-written code</s> code that makes assumptions about the environment. Specifically, code that treats `for..in` as though it loops through array element indexes (it doesn't, it looks through *object property names*) will get messed up if you add to the `Array` prototype. (That's probably why jQuery doesn't do it.)

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/agoce3)

Comment: Why did you put the definition of indexOf in a closure instead of like:     if (!Array.prototype.indexOf) { Array.prototype.indexOf = function(elm) {...};}; ?

Comment: @thomasmalt: Because I like functions to have names, and unfortunately that's the only way that's compatible with IE (JScript) to give the function a name without creating a global symbol and without creating the function if we don't have to: http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2010/03/anonymouses-anonymous.html Your way is great other than the function not having a name.

Comment: Thanks. I normally prefer to extend by assigning anonymous functions to variables. For me that enhances readability and makes it easy to create well formatted, well documented, source code. :)

Comment: @thomasmalt: Fair enough. I like to have function names in my call stack when using a debugger. :-) Hopefully, someday, Microsoft will fix the JScript bug that prevents just using a named function expression like `Array.prototype.indexOf = function Array_indexOf() { ... }`. But sadly, not even JScript 6 (IE8) fixes it: http://jsbin.com/alexe3/2  Maybe IE9, they're doing a *lot* of standards work...

Comment: And debugging is a really good reason to use named functions. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: @Crowder Thanks your first code snippet works fine for me. I did small changes as per my requirement.

Comment: @Kamlesh: Good deal, glad that helped.

Answer (score 7):

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
b = [2, 1, 5]

comp = a.filter(function(e) { return b.indexOf(e) < 0 })
```

see [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [Array.indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) for more details and degradation options.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you're after the *relative complement* of `b` in `a`.

```
function complement(a, b) {

  // convert A to an associative array
  var myHash = {};
  for (var i = 0; i < a.length; ++i) {
    myHash[a[i]] = 1;
  }

  // remove the elements that exist in B
  for (var i = 0; i < b.length; ++i) {
    delete myHash[b[i]];
  }

  // what's left is A \ B
  // assumes that no-one broke Array by adding new properties to the prototype
  return Object.keys(myHash);
}

// test
var a = [1, 2, 3, 4];
var b = [1, 2];
var c = complement(a, b);
alert(c);
```

This should scale well for larger arrays, since it uses hash table indexing rather than linear searches to remove the unwanted elements.

Comment: hash-based solutions don't work when (some of) array elements are Objects.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another solution which uses [Array.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [Array.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

```
function arrayDifference(a, b) {
  return a.filter((x) => !b.includes(x));
}

const a = [1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4]
const b = [1, 2]

arrayDifference(a,b) // returns [3, 4]
```